# Find this limits $\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\bigl(n(H_{2n}-H_{n}-\ln{2})+\frac{1}{4}\bigr)$

Tags: limits, asymptotics

**Question1:**

> Find this limits
>
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^2\left(n(H_{2n}-H_{n}-\ln{2})+\dfrac{1}{4}\right)$$
>
> where $$H_{n}=1+\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{1}{3}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n}$$

**Question 2:**

> Can we obtain a higher asymptotic expansion?

I know $$ \lim_{n\to\infty}n(H_{2n}-H_{n}-\ln{2})=-\dfrac{1}{4}$$
this following well know
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}f(\dfrac{i}{n})-\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx\right)=\dfrac{f(1)-f(0)}{2}$$

Comment: You can use the [Asymptotic expression of $H_n$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).. it can be derived by the [Euler-Maclaurin Summation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula).

Comment: $\large{\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n\left[\, H_{2n} - H_{n} -\ln\left(\,2\,\right)\,\right]=\color{#c00000}{-}\,{1 \over 4}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
It would be easier to use the
[Harmonic Number Digamma Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Applications)
$\ds{H_{a} - H_{b}=\Psi\pars{a + 1} - \Psi\pars{b + 1}}$ such that:
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}
n^{2}\braces{n\bracks{H_{2n} - H_{n} -\ln\pars{2}} + {1 \over 4}}}
\\[5mm]&=\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n^{2}\braces{
n\bracks{\dsc{\Psi\pars{2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{n + 1}} - \ln\pars{2}}+{1 \over 4}}
\tag{1}
\end{align}
With the
[Digamma Asymptotic Expansion and Recurrence Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_258.htm) $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{when}\ n \gg 1~}}$:
\begin{align}
&\dsc{\Psi\pars{2n + 1} - \Psi\pars{n + 1}}
=\bracks{\Psi\pars{2n} + {1 \over 2n}} - \bracks{\Psi\pars{n} + {1 \over n}}
\\[5mm]&\sim-\,{1 \over 2n}
+\bracks{\ln\pars{2n} - {1 \over 4n} - {1 \over 48n^{2}}}
-\bracks{\ln\pars{n} - {1 \over 2n} - {1 \over 12n^{2}}}
\\[5mm]&=\ln\pars{2} - {1 \over 4n} + {1 \over 16n^{2}}
\end{align}
The next terms are, at least, of order $\ds{1 \over n^{4}}$. It is clear that:
$$\color{#66f}{\large
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}n^{2}\braces{n\bracks{H_{2n} - H_{n} -\ln\pars{2}}-{1 \over 4}}}
=\color{#66f}{\large \infty}
$$

Comment: oh,It's power of  fouth! Thank you

Comment: I'm glad you founf it useful. Thanks.